# How to use Qt with Rust?

Tags: windows, qt, cmake, rust, qt5

Today I've decided to learn Rust and I was wondering how hard is to use Qt with Rust. The first Google results gave me [qt.rs](https://github.com/kitech/qt.rs), so I've decided to give it a shot.

My Qt installation lives in `C:\Qt\5.7\` and `Qt5Config.cmake` lives in `C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\lib\cmake\Qt5`

What I've tried is:

- `git clone https://github.com/kitech/qt.inline.git`
- `cd qt.inline && mkdir build`
- `cmake -D Qt5_DIR=C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\lib\cmake\Qt5 -G "Sublime Text 2 - Ninja" ..`
- `cmake -D Qt5Core_DIR=C:\\Qt\\5.7\\msvc2015_64\\lib\\cmake\\Qt5Core -D Qt5Gui_DIR=C:\\Qt\\5.7\\msvc2015_64\\lib\\cmake\\Qt5Gui -D Qt5Widgets_DIR=C:\\Qt\\5.7\\msvc2015_64\\lib\\cmake\\Qt5Widgets -G "Sublime Text 2 - Ninja" ..`
- `cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\\Qt\\5.7\\msvc2015_64\\ -G "Sublime Text 2 - Ninja" ..`

but the result was a bunch of errors:

[image]

I've also tried other Qt folders like {`C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\lib\cmake`, `C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64\lib`, `C:\Qt\5.7\msvc2015_64`, `C:\Qt\5.7\`, `C:\Qt`} with the same luck.

How could I solve this one?

What would Rust's equivalent to Python's pyqt/pyside be? Is there any "official" Qt Rust package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[qt.inline](https://github.com/kitech/qt.inline) depends on Qt. Assuming you installed Qt in your system, the errors suggest you didn't specify where Qt is installed.

On a "normal" project using `find_package(Qt5 ...)`, you would have done:

```
cmake .. -D Qt5_DIR=/path/to/qt -G "Sublime Text 2 - Ninja"
```

Where `/path/to/qt` is the directory in your Qt install containing `Qt5Config.cmake`. Given `<prefix>` is the root dir of your Qt install, this should be something like `<prefix>/lib/cmake/Qt5`.

qt.inline is more specific and [ask explicitly](https://github.com/kitech/qt.inline/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L16) for specific modules of Qt, namely `Qt5Core`, `Qt5Gui` and `Qt5Widgets`. So use the same procedure with these modules:

```
cmake -D Qt5Core_DIR=/path/to/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
      -D Qt5Gui_DIR=/path/to/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake
      -D Qt5Widgets_DIR=/path/to/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake
      ...
```

Comment: @BPL I edited my answer. Just replace the paths with `C:/Qt/5.7/msvc2015_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Core` for `Qt5Core_DIR`, and so on for `Qt5Gui_DIR` and `Qt5Widgets_DIR`. Always prefer "/" to the native "\" in paths. CMake may interpret them as escaping characters.

Comment: Your attempt `cmake -D Qt5_DIR=C:/Qt/5.7/msvc2015_64/lib/cmake/Qt5 -D Qt5Gui_DIR=C:/Qt/5.7/msvc2015_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui -D Qt5Widgets_DIR=C:/Qt/5.7/msvc2015_64/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets -G "Sublime Text 2 - Ninja" ..` is the right one. qt.inline is ill formed: the file `qversionnumber.cxx` listed in `src/core/mod.cmake` is indeed missing. There is a branch in the repo without that file listed: change your repo to this branch using `git checkout qt5.5` in a git bash

Comment: This should be a branch made for Qt5.5 and you have Qt5.7: it may fail. If it fails, get back to the master branch and remove the line adding `qversionnumber.cxx` in `src/core/mod.cmake` (hoping there will be no more error after that), or install Qt5.5

Comment: I've forked this project [here](https://github.com/brupelo/qt.inline). After commenting some unexisting autogenerated wrapper files and commenting some specific compiler stuff I got the Sublime Project using `cmake -D Qt5Core_DIR=C:\\Qt\\5.7\\msvc2015_64\\lib\\cmake\\Qt5Core -D Qt5Gui_DIR=C:\\Qt\\5.7\\msvc2015_64\\lib\\cmake\\Qt5Gui -D Qt5Widgets_DIR=C:\\Qt\\5.7\\msvc2015_64\\lib\\cmake\\Qt5Widg‌​ets -G "Sublime Text 2 - Ninja" ..`. Problem comes when I try to build it, here's the [log](https://bpaste.net/show/2a6fd5072a96)

Comment: I looked the corresponding code and how the cmake project is configured. It seems qt.inline is not compatible with visual :/

Comment: In the meantime I've switched to this another [alternative](https://github.com/rust-qt), it works out of the box. It takes 5500s to be built on debug mode and 1873s in release mode. Now i'm trying to figure out how to vendor it for not rebuilding over and over. I guess I'll validate your answer, let's consider it helped out to create the *.sublime-project, even if building it was a nightmare ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems qt.rs is without any update for many years.

Suggest looking at [Ritual](https://rust-qt.github.io/) instead also on [GitHub](https://github.com/rust-qt)